# Как правильно пишется (выявление ее не пригодности или на не пригодность)?

Tags: грамотная-речь

*Произвести проверку средств индивидуальной защиты для выявления ее не пригодности*
или
*произвести проверку средств индивидуальной защиты для выявления ее на не пригодность*?

Comment: Непригодность - слитно. Тогда 1-й вариант станет грамматически правильным, если ещё заменить "её" на "их" (средств). 2-й вариант совсем кривой.

Answer (score 1):

Понятие пригодности тяготеет к использованию с зависимыми словами (пригодность или пригодный к чему), без таковых лучше говорить о "годности" (подразумевает пригодность к использованию по прямому назначению). Прилагательное "непригодный" (с отрицанием) в этом смысле исключение, поскольку "негодный" имеет другое значение и употребление.

> Произвести проверку *годности* средств индивидуальной защиты.
>
> Произвести проверку средств индивидуальной защиты на предмет их
>   *годности*.
>
> Произвести проверку средств индивидуальной защиты для выявления
>   *непригодных*.